# ECMA7 static prototypes is not yet supported in Meteor, what is a good workaround?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, ecmascript-6

I would like to use ECMA static proptypes within my React code. Unfortunately this throws the following Babel error 
`Missing class properties transform.`. As far as I'm aware this is because Meteor does not yet support stage 0 ECMA proposals.

From reading various threads it seems like it may be possible to resolve this by amending some babel configs, however I'm not too familiar with Babel so  would rather avoid screwing with it too much. How can I express the below static /proptypes logic in an alternative, supported fashion?

Thanks!

```
import React from 'react';
import bookSingleLine from '../Kooks/Table/BookSingleLine';
import TrackerReact from 'meteor/ultimatejs:tracker-react';


export default class bookListingTable extends TrackerReact(React.Component) {

static propTypes = {
LimitProp: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired
  }
static defaultProps ={
    LimitProp: 5,
  }
```

Comment: The transform you're looking for is [class-properties-transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) and it's actually made it to Stage 2 ([preset-stage-2](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/)). See the linked pages on how to add the presets to your workflow

Comment: Thanks for the detail, I'll look to add these presets going forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just manually assign the static properties instead of declaring them in the class body (which is not supported in ES7):

```
export default class BookListingTable extends TrackerReact(React.Component) {
    …
}
BookListingTable.propTypes = {
    LimitProp: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired
};
BookListingTable.defaultProps = {
    LimitProp: 5
};
```

Comment: This is the approach I'd use. Most examples follow this convention and linters won't flag it as an issue.

Comment: Thanks Bergi and Tim, this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

There is a better approach today, it makes you use static.

[add the following package:](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/)

```
meteor npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-class-properties
```

Edit your package.json in your project and add there the following to make [the package work:](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/#top)

```
 "babel": {
    "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]

  }
```