# ES7 static causing ESLint Parsing Error: Unexpected token =

Tags: javascript, eslint

Good evening! I am linting my code and have a `Parsing error: Unexpected token =` when linting the following ES7 code in a React component:

```
static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
}
```

The component is a class based component:

`class Transactions extends Component {`

I have added `babel-eslint` to my `eslintrc.json` file:

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "plugins": [
    "react",
    "react-native"
  ],
  "ecmaFeatures": {
    "jsx": true
  },
  "extends": ["standard", "standard-react"]
}
```

The versions of the dependencies are set in my `package.json` as follows:

```
"babel-eslint": "^6.0.4",
"eslint-plugin-babel": "^3.2.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^5.0.1",
"eslint": "^2.2.0",
"eslint-config-standard": "^5.1.0",
"eslint-config-standard-jsx": "^1.1.1",
"eslint-config-standard-react": "^2.3.0",
"eslint-loader": "^1.3.0",
"eslint-plugin-promise": "^1.0.8",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^4.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-standard": "^1.3.2"
```

Any ideas would be good, struggling to find a resolution online beyond using `babel-eslint` as a parser.

Thank you :-)

Comment: It's not ES7, but an experimental babel plugin that your config activates. Eslint won't like it (at least with default settings)

Comment: Hey @Bergi - thanks - which plugin specifically? Do you know what I need to do? Thanks

Comment: It's https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/ iirc, probably a dependency of `react`.

Comment: Am not using that plugin.

Comment: But you're using its features? Even if you don't explicitly enable it, it must be part of something you have in your settings. You can [easily avoid the syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39701243/1048572) though

Comment: Thanks Bergi, that has sorted it :)

Answer (score 0):

You should put your contextTypes outside your class.

Example:

```
class Transactions extends Component {
   ....
   ....
}

Transactions.contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
}
```